# Searching a nested Gridview ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add in a search to my GridView. I have a collapsable gridview though. So for searching purposes, is there a way to search for something within the collapsed gridview and it return collapsed results and then expand upon the item to view what was searched.

I've made a collapsed textbook gridview with thousands of records. Paging is set up and I have about 55 pages of records in collapsed form.

[image]

So if there was a search for book title "College accounting" it would show the collapsed form and then to view what was searched the user could just expand each item that returned "college accounting".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little code to get you started. But I don't know if looping all gridcolumns and cells is an efficient way to search through data though...

In this example the code will stop looking for more results on the first found searchterm in the grids. If you want the last you should remove `if (searchTermFound == false)` from the loop.
If you want multiple result matched you should store the found columns and cells in a List or Array.
With the found `rowIndexParent` and `rowIndexChild` values you can expand your grid on the row you need.

```
    private void searchGridView(string searchTerm)
    {
        int rowIndexParent = -1;
        int cellIndexParent = -1;
        int rowIndexChild = -1;
        int cellIndexChild = -1;
        bool searchTermFound = false;

        //loop all rows in parent grid
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //remove this if you want the last match displayed as found, not the first
            if (searchTermFound == false)
            {
                //loop all cells in parent grid
                for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    string cellContent = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
                    if (cellContent.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()))
                    {
                        rowIndexParent = i;
                        cellIndexParent = j;
                        searchTermFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //find the nested grid and cast it
                GridView gv = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("GridView2") as GridView;

                //loop all rows in child grid
                for (int ii = 0; ii < gv.Rows.Count; ii++)
                {
                    //loop all cells in child grid
                    for (int jj = 0; jj < gv.Columns.Count; jj++)
                    {
                        string cellContent = gv.Rows[ii].Cells[jj].Text;

                        if (cellContent.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()))
                        {
                            rowIndexParent = i;

                            rowIndexChild = ii;
                            cellIndexChild = jj;
                            searchTermFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //cellIndexParent > -1 means searchTerm is found in parent grid, not child
        if (searchTermFound == true && cellIndexParent > -1)
        {
            Response.Write("Searchterm \"" + searchTerm + "\" found in parent grid: row " + rowIndexParent + ", column " + cellIndexParent + ".");
        }
        else if (searchTermFound == true)
        {
            Response.Write("Searchterm \"" + searchTerm + "\" found in child grid: row " + rowIndexChild + ", column " + cellIndexChild + ", parent row " + rowIndexParent + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Searchterm \"" + searchTerm + "\" not found.");
        }
    }
```

> Note that this only works with BoundField columns, not TemplateField and AutoGenerated Columns. See below.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <!-- search terms in these columns can be found -->
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field01" HeaderText="Column A" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field02" HeaderText="Column B" />

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- search terms in this column cannot be found -->
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field05").ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <!-- search terms in these columns can be found -->
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="field03" HeaderText="Column C" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="field04" HeaderText="Column D" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: So would I just set the textbox I'm using for the search term equal to search term? txtSearch.Text = searchTerm; and then call this method on btnSearch_click?

Comment: That will work. Just validate the length of the search term to be at least 3 characters, otherwise you will get a lot of false positives.

Comment: is there an easy way to display just the found results from the search? or is that a bit of work? because this thing works great! now I just need to refresh my gridview to only show found information.

Comment: That would be a bit of work. If you want that I think you are better off searching the source of the GridView and just bind the results. You could remove a row after it has been searched and has no results, but I don't think that would be a good approach. Maybe as a last resort if you don't have control over the source.

Comment: what is meant by searching the source of the gridview? like the sqldatasource2?

Comment: All the data probably comes from a database. And somewhere in sqldatasource there is a reference to a query or stored procedure that gets you the data that you need. You could send also send the searchterm to the database as a parameter and let the database do the searching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121397/discussion-between-norque-and-vdwwd).